# How to Asynchronous update to ObservableCollection items?

Tags: c#, async-await, observablecollection

I know it's an old question. 
Here's some codes. It works fine with `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(Quotes, _stocksLock);`

```
private void _source_QuoteArrived(Quote Q)
{
    Quotes.Add(Q);
}
```

Question 1: In xaml file there's listview binding with `Quotes`. But why cross threading happens here? My understanding of cross threading is it only happens when you do it explicitly. Like the example below. When you explicitly use an UI element (`label1` here), crossing threading error occurs.But I am using data binding here which is twoway. Why do i need `EnableCollectionSynchronization` here?

```
 private  void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
     string result =  client.GetStringAsync("http://microsoft.com");
     label1.Text = result;
 }
```

Quetion 2: Assuming there exists cross threading with data binding?The above `button1_Click`example can be solved with `async await` But  Why can't i do sth similar just using `async await`

```
private async void _source_QuoteArrived(Quote Q)
{
    await Task.Run(() => Quotes.Add(Q));
}
```

to update listview in the gui. I tried it with corss threading error.
I thought i messed up some concepts. Plz help.

Comment: Your second code example shouldn't compile. `GetStringAsync` returns a `Task<string>`. As you're not using `await`, the compiler should emit an error.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov True. Let me clear, the second code has nothing to do with the other codes. I just wanna illustrate when i thought cross threading happens.  What i do not know's why it's the same case with data-binding. And why `await Task.Run(() => Quotes.Add(Q));` did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do i need EnableCollectionSynchronization here?

If by *here* you mean your second code example, than you don't need any `EnableCollectionSynchronization` there. Although your second example wont compile, if done properly, will execute `label1.Text = result;` on the UI thread, and no cross-thread error should occur. The `SynchronizationContext` will be in charge of marshaling work back onto the UI thread.

> But why can't i do something similar just using async await?

I think you're confusing the usage of the `Task Parallel Library` and the `async-await` feature. `async-await` is a tool which is ment to "ease the pain" of writing **asynchronous** code. Asynchronousy isn't parallelalism:

> When you run something asynchronously it means it is non-blocking, you execute it without waiting for it to complete and carry on with other things. Parallelism means to run multiple things at the same time, in parallel.

As your code is structed right now, you can't use `Task.Run` to update `Quotes`, because it is a UI bound property.

Most of the time you'll find the use of `async-await` working naturally with I/O bound operations.

Comment: I don't get it. `async button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){string result = await   client.GetStringAsync("http://microsoft.com");label1.Text = result;}` works. The marshaling heppens here with `async await`

Comment: Why `await Task.Run(() => Quotes.Add(Q));` did not work with marshaling to the Ui thread.<which is an listview binding to Quotes>

Comment: Because `Task.Run` executes `Quotes.Add` on a threadpool thread, which creates a cross-thread exception. The fact that you `await Task.Run` doesn't change that fact.

Comment: But i thought `string result = await client.GetStringAsync("http://microsoft.com")`; also execute on a thread different from `label1.Text = result;` and await changes the result.

Comment: Nope. `GetStringAsync` will not use a different thread to execute. That operation is naturally asynchronous all the way down to the OS.

Comment: **GetStringAsync will not use a different thread to execute** Do u mean `GetStringAsync` use the thread same as the UI thread, then you do not need `await` here to do the marshaling.It does not make sense.

Comment: You use `await` in order to yield control back to the calling method while the IO bound operation executes. I think you have a misunderstanding of what `async-await` means. Have you read any tutorials?